# Vanilla JS: Filtered Dropdown Select Options for Safari

Tags: javascript, select, filter, ecmascript-6, safari

I'm trying to filter an array corresponding to a select-element's option-children.
Of course there are a bunch of ways to do this in Chrome, but I was trying to get it working in Safari. Other Posts here on Stack Overflow said it couldn't be done without recreating the select element's children with each and every keyup- so that's exactly what I've done.

**I've got it working within safari currently filtering out** indicating it can be edited, but currently it is not re-adding previously filtered items, which seems odd as the filter method is non-destructive, so I'm not exactly sure what it is that needs work but I'm sure its something dumb and simple, and then hopefully this helps others in the future.

codeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-snow-iwlxf1?file=/src/index.js

**Note:** The function keeps on referencing the elements located within the Dom every keyup event. Of course, it's these elements that are getting permanently filtered. Right now I think it's best to define it once, outside the function so that the value is not redefined like the new one...

**Snippet:**

```js
const dropdownList = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
const origOptArray = Array.from(dropdownList.options).map((option) => {
  return option.value;
});

const filterOptions = (inputValue) => {
  const dropdownList = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  const options = dropdownList.options;

  console.log(inputValue);
  const removeSelected = (options) => {
    // if the first option is a select placeholder, remove it from the options array
    if (
      options[0].value === "" ||
      options[0].textContent === "-- SELECT --" ||
      options[0].disabled === true ||
      options[0].value === null ||
      options[0].value === undefined
    ) {
      options[0].selected = false;
      const filteredOptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(options, 1);
      return filteredOptions;
    } else {
      return options;
    }
  };
  // Use the slice method to create a new array of options that excludes the first option
  const filteredOptions = removeSelected(options);

  // Use the filter function to create a new array of options that contain the input value
  const matchingOptions = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    filteredOptions,
    (option) => option.value.toUpperCase().startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase())
  );

  // The appendChild method would probably make more sense here since we're pulling from
  // the original array. But then is the first array (matchikgOptions) even needed?
  const newMAtchingOptions = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    // I'm thinking the origOptArray goes here:
    filteredOptions,
    (option) => !option.value.toUpperCase().startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase())
  );

  console.log(matchingOptions, newMAtchingOptions);

  // Remove all the options from the dropdown list
  while (dropdownList.firstChild) {
    dropdownList.removeChild(dropdownList.firstChild);
  }

  // // Add the first option back to the dropdown list
  const firstOption = document.createElement("option");
  firstOption.value = "";
  firstOption.textContent = "-- SELECT --";
  firstOption.disabled = true;
  dropdownList.append(firstOption);

  // Create new option elements for the matching options
  const newOptions = matchingOptions.map((option) => {
    const newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = option.value;
    newOption.textContent = option.textContent;
    return newOption;
  });
  // Add the new options to the dropdown list
  dropdownList.append(...newOptions);
};

const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const firstOption = document.createElement("option");
firstOption.value = "";
firstOption.textContent = "-- SELECT --";
firstOption.disabled = true;
dropdownList[0].textContent = "";
dropdownList[0].append(firstOption);

const inputField = document.getElementById("myInput");
inputField.addEventListener("input", function () {
  filterOptions(inputField.value);
});
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="./src/index.js" defer></script>
    <title>SearchFilter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search" />
        <select id="myDropdown">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="name">Name</option>
          <option value="nameste">Nameste</option>
          <option value="email">Email</option>
          <option value="emu">Emu</option>
          <option value="phone">Phone</option>
          <option value="rolex">Rolex</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS... I've gotten new items to add so it definitely is possible.. and so I'm surprised no-one has answered yet but I just haven't gotten the right mixture of code to ensure no duplicates.

Comment: I find the question not very clear. *"trying to filter an array corresponding to a select-element's option-children"*: filtering the array is the problem? Or filtering the select-options? If it is the first, then Safari plays no role. If it is the second, the array is irrelevant. This could be phrased more clearly, and it would be good to include a runnable snippet (via the toolbar in the editor), so that running it in different browsers shows that the problem is specific to Safari.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment (no sarcasm). In a nutshell, a select element(dropdown) has option elements as children(as you would expect). The search (text input) to the left of the dropdown(searches and filters) elements that do not contain the text input of the text input... Reasons this hasn't been answered before:  There are a few jQuery post which. I didn't test because  I can only use vanilla and typically people just use packages because they are just easier - I've been told, I'm in no way a master lol.

Comment: The array was created because in other posts, it was said that it could not be done without basing the option elements off an array/object: as opposed to the HTML itself. I'll set up a snippet rn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are getting the options to filter using `const options = dropdownList.options;` each time you run the `filterOptions` function, but since the dropdown is already filtered, you get only what's left after the last filter operation. If you filter the original set of options instead, it will work (see snippet).

Best of luck with your project:)

```js
const _dropdownList = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
const origOptArray = Array.from(_dropdownList.options).map((option) => ({
  value: option.value,
  textContent: option.textContent
}));

const filterOptions = (inputValue) => {
  const dropdownList = document.getElementById("myDropdown");

  // Use the filter function to create a new array of options that contain the input value
  const matchingOptions = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    origOptArray,
    (option) => option.value.toUpperCase().startsWith(inputValue.toUpperCase())
  );

  // Remove all the options from the dropdown list
  while (dropdownList.firstChild) {
    dropdownList.removeChild(dropdownList.firstChild);
  }

  // // Add the first option back to the dropdown list
  const firstOption = document.createElement("option");
  firstOption.value = "";
  firstOption.textContent = "-- SELECT --";
  firstOption.disabled = true;
  dropdownList.append(firstOption);

  // Create new option elements for the matching options
  const newOptions = matchingOptions.map((option) => {
    const newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = option.value;
    newOption.textContent = option.textContent;
    return newOption;
  });
  // Add the new options to the dropdown list
  dropdownList.append(...newOptions);
};

const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const firstOption = document.createElement("option");
firstOption.value = "";
firstOption.textContent = "-- SELECT --";
firstOption.disabled = true;
_dropdownList[0].textContent = "";
_dropdownList[0].append(firstOption);

const inputField = document.getElementById("myInput");
inputField.addEventListener("input", function () {
  filterOptions(inputField.value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="./src/index.js" defer></script>
    <title>SearchFilter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search" />
        <select id="myDropdown">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="name">Name</option>
          <option value="nameste">Nameste</option>
          <option value="email">Email</option>
          <option value="emu">Emu</option>
          <option value="phone">Phone</option>
          <option value="rolex">Rolex</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I needed, and thank you for the explanation as well! It says I have 3 hours before I can award you the bounty!